# How do I force intercept on a python linear regression plot?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, seaborn

How do I force the line and equation through 0 on this dataframe? I only know how to make a line that is the best fit and equation to match.Below is the code of the best fit line without force intercept through 0. Any help getting forced intercept is appreciated!

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import scipy as sp
r, p = sp.stats.pearsonr(x=df['mass(mg)'], y=df['Abs'])
sns.regplot(x=df['mass(mg)'],y=df['Abs']).set(Title='biuret standard plot')

def equation(x,y):
    x_mean = x.mean()
    y_mean = y.mean()
    
    B1_num = ((x - x_mean) * (y - y_mean)).sum()
    B1_den = ((x - x_mean)**2).sum()
    B1 = B1_num / B1_den
    B0 = y_mean - (B1*x_mean)
    
    reg_line = 'y = {} + {}β'.format(B0, round(B1, 3))
    
    return (B0, B1, reg_line)
equation(df['mass(mg)'],df['Abs'])
```

Comment: Seaborn hard codes in an intercept if you let it do the regression. You could plot it yourself on top with the slope you get from `numpy.linalg.lstsq`.

Comment: You could trying using `curve_fit` from scipy.optimize package. Simply set your fit function to be in the form of "y=mx", therefore eliminating the y-intercept as a fit parameter. This way, the best fit will always go through the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn's linear regression won't let you do that.

So if you are trying to get the line to go through the origin i.e. (0,0) then your equation is y=mx. There is no B0 if you're doing this. So we use numpy.linalf.lstq to do least squares and force it through origin. And we also add 0 coordinates so it draws on. Taking in your values for mass and Abs, see below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# I'm adding a 0 in both x and y axis to force a line drawn.
x = np.array([0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.5])
y = np.array([0, 0.596, 0.464, 0.333, 0.201, 0.121, 0.062])

# We only need a*x. so to figure out a we use lstsq from numpy
# Our x matrix is one dimensional, it needs to be two dimensional to use lstsq so:
x = x[:,np.newaxis]
a, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, a*x, 'r-')
plt.xlim([0, 6])
plt.ylim([0, 0.7])
plt.show()
print(f"y = {a} x + 0")
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Feel free to add labelling etc.

Hope this helps, please mark this as the answer if it does!

Answer (score 0):

`sns.regplot` has a parameter `truncate=` which default to `True` and limits the line to the given data.  With `truncate=False` the line is extended until the border.  You can set the `xlim` before calling `sns.regplot` to a suitable range.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
plt.xlim(-10, 80)
sns.regplot(data=tips, x='total_bill', y='tip', truncate=False, color='turquoise')
plt.axvline(0, color='gray', ls='--')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.regplot extended till the borders]

If you want to extend till `x=0` and still limit the right to the data limit, you can set the `xlim` both before and after the `regplot`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
plt.xlim(0, tips['total_bill'].max())
sns.regplot(data=tips, x='total_bill', y='tip', truncate=False, color='coral')
plt.axvline(0, color='gray', ls='--')
plt.xlim(-5, tips['total_bill'].max() + 5)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.regplot extended till zero]